# Javascript Array becomes an Object when passed to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, slickgrid

I am Using the slick grid JS Plugin for grouping a table rows. So I need to pass some parameters for the function call. So I tried passing an array as a parameter.I Made the array using for loop. But when a array value pass through a function in the for loop it becomes a OBJECT which is Undefined.
Below is my code snippet

```
function groupBy(length,array) {                
            var newArray=[];        
                for(i=0;i<length;i++)
                {
                    newArray[i]={
                    getter: array[i],
                    formatter: function (g) {                               
                        if(g.value == null)
                        {                       
                            return array[i]+":  " + (g.value ? "True" : "False") + "  <span style='color:green'>(" + g.count + " items)</span>";                            
                        }
                        return array[i]+":  " + g.value + "  <span style='color:green'>(" + g.count + " items)</span>";
                    },
                    aggregators: [
                      new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Avg("percentComplete"),
                      new Slick.Data.Aggregators.Sum("cost")
                    ],
                    aggregateCollapsed: false,
                    lazyTotalsCalculation: true
                    };

                }               
                dataView.setGrouping(newArray);             
            }
```

the array value worked until this statement `getter: array[i],` and when it pass through this function in for loop it becomes undefined or an Object.

```
formatter: function (g) {                               
    if(g.value == null)
    {                       
        return array[i]+":  " + (g.value ? "True" : "False") + "  <span style='color:green'>(" + g.count + " items)</span>";                            
    }
    return array[i]+":  " + g.value + "  <span style='color:green'>(" + g.count + " items)</span>";
   }
```

Please help me to get rid of this.

Comment: Would you be able to made a JSFiddle and pinpoint your issue?

Comment: i can't it is working through a js plugin. the plugin is functioning properly

Comment: Can you please show the code where you call the ```groupBy``` function.

Comment: `var value='';   
   var checks=$('.checkGroup:checked').length;
   var arr = $.map($('.checkGroup:checked'), function(e, i){  
    value=e.value;
    return e.value;
   });
   groupBy(checks,arr,value);` this is where i am calling the groupBy() function

Comment: Sorry for the bad indentation

Comment: hi, i tried ur code by commenting some external lib code but didnt encounter problem as u mentioned array not acting as array when in function call, if i understood it correctly. i simply created array of some numbers passed to function and added console log n it got printed in loop, just before newArray = initialization...

Comment: try that code with slickgrid plugin by calling the `dataView.setGrouping();`  method. Pass the array as the parameter which must in the form of           `[  getter: value, formatter: value, aggregators: value]`

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Array mutates to object for no reason when passed as param. I need to use it immediately, before it's passed through a method... it's awful